# Pourquoi le mot petit est-il si répandu ?

Tags: lexique

Selon le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française* (neuvième édition, 1992 via *CNRTL*):

> *[Petit](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/petit)* est un des adjectifs les plus couramment employés dans la langue française ; il entre dans un très grand nombre de locutions et
>   d'expressions qui, dans la plupart des cas, sont expliquées au mot
>   principal.

La liste d'exemples de ce phénomène me paraît sans fin (e.g., *Petit* Larousse, *Petit* Robert [avec des centaines de pages], Le *Petit* prince, Le *Petit* Nicolas, La *Petite* Fadette, *petit* à *petit*, etc.) et comme un locuteur non-natif, j’en suis étonné et je voudrais savoir s’il y en a des explications logiques (liées soit au mot *petit/e* lui-même, soit à la langue française (ou aux ceux/celles qui la parlent), soit d'autres choses, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'affirmation d'une popularité spécifique de **petit** dans la langue française apparaît sans fondement.

Bien qu'il soit exact que **petit** est un adjectif courant en français, il ne fait aucun doute que la même chose peut être dite à propos des autres langues.

Voici une comparaison sommaire de l'utilisation de petit par rapport à ses antonymes dans quelques langues européennes.

- Français

[image]

- Espagnol

[image]

- Italien

[image]

- Anglais

[image]

- Allemand

[image]

L'espagnol montre un écart plus important que l'italien ou le français. Une explication possible est la grande popularité des suffixes (*-ito, -ita, -iño, -illo, -uelo*) en espagnol alors que les équivalents français (ex: *-ette*) sont plus rarement rencontrés.

La français ne présente pas de différence significative face aux langues abordées, et en particulier l'adjectif *petit* ne semble pas susciter une « adoration »<sup>1</sup> particulière, ni même une place prépondérante puisque l'adjectif *grand* montre une fréquence d'utilisation bien plus élevée.

Affaire classée, ou pas...

<sup>1</sup> Terme utilisé dans la question originale.

Comment: Les fréquences relatives montrent des divergences suffisamment importantes pour légitimer la possibilité d'un usage subjectif du mot; remarquez la fréquence d'utilisation du mot dans l'anglais: elle est plus grande et de beaucoup que dans les autres langues; est-ce que la civilisation anglaise serait axée spécialement sur les choses de ce monde qui sont petites? Pas nécessairement, je crois même qu'une explication ne soit pas à rechercher dans cette direction. (suite au prochain commentaire)@jlliagre

Comment: La question qui a été posée, même si son auteur (@dimitris) n'a pas cerné une réalité bien précise ou n'a pas su l'exprimer soulève toujours une grande question dans le domaine de l'utilisation subjective des mots; non, l'affaire n'est pas classée, tout au moins pas dans le domaine de la linguistique "at large".@jlliagre

Comment: Il ya un élément que ces graphiques ne montrent pas: en allemand et en néerlandais (peut-être dans d'autres langues ?), on exprime très couramment cette idée de "petit" par l'apposition d'un diminutif "-chen" ou"-je/-tje" (ou "-ke" en néerlandais de Belgique familier). Ex: un "petit café" est "een kopje koffie" en néerlandais ("kop" signfiant "tasse").

Comment: allemand: mutterchen; Mutterchen, komm, du musst aufstehen. (traduit en français par « petite mère»

Comment: L'explication pour l'anglais c'est que *little* est aussi un adverbe, et est probablement plus utilisé en tant qu'adverbe qu'en tant qu'adjectif.

Comment: @user168676 Les comparaisons sont moins pertinentes avec les langues non romanes avec lesquelles il est en effet plus difficile de trouver une correspondance fidèle. Il serait intéressant de trouver des chiffres pour le grec (micro vs mega ?).

Comment: @Greg C'est aussi vrai pour l'espagnol et l'italien (suffixes iño/ito/illo/uelo/... en esp.) *Le petit Poucet* se traduit je crois par *El Pulgarcito* (*pulgar* = pouce).

Comment: Et *Puccettino* en italien.

Comment: @jlliagre Ngram ne donne pas des chiffres pour le grec (sauf erreur de ma part). Il faut chercher : **μικρός+μικρή+μικρό+μικροί+μικρές+μικρά vs μεγάλος+μεγάλη+μεγάλο+μεγάλοι+μεγάλες+μεγάλα** (respectivement, petit : masculin singulier+feminin singulier+neutre singulier+masculin pluriel+feminin pluriel+neutre pluriel vs grand : masculin singulier+feminin singulier+neutre singulier+masculin pluriel+feminin pluriel+neutre pluriel ; compliqué quand même:-)!).

Answer (score 0):

Il me semble que les cas « Petit Larousse » et « Petit Robert » n'entrent pas dans la catégorie appréhendée : malgré leurs centaines de pages ce sont de petits volumes comparés aux grands dictionnaires de chez Larousse et Robert, lesquels comprennent des milliers de pages; ces caractérisations sont factuelles pour ces ouvrages. Il se trouve qu'une version raccourcie du dictionaire d'Oxford a été appelée « The Shorter Oxford Dictionary » (3800 pages); on est donc obligé d'utiliser un mot ou un autre dont les connotations communiquent ces états de chose comparés. Je dois dire qu'une remarque similaire est applicable au terme "petit à petit"; qu'est-ce que l'anglais utilise en traduction? « little by little »; jusqu'à présent aucun des exemples choisis ne convient. Si on a lu « Le Petit Prince » on sait bien que le personnage est un personnage enfantin; « Le Petit Prince » n'entraine pas d'équivoque » alors que « Le jeune Prince » ou encore « Le Prince » ferait penser à autre chose; n'oublions pas que le titre d'un livre est une sorte d'annoncement de ce que l'on trouve dans ses pages. Donc aucun de vos exemples ne sont convaincants. Vous auriez mentionné l'habitude des gens de France et en particulier des femmes d'appeler les bébés des petits bébés alors qu'ils n'est pas question de comparaison d'âge, je crois que le cas aurait été pertinent. Vous auriez avancé le cas que l'on relève dans la littérature populaire en ce qui concerne les personnes agées, je réfère là à l'appellation « la petite mère » qui est issue sans aucun doute de la culture populaire à son niveau le plus humble, j'aurais identifié dans votre appréhension un phénomène psycho-linguistique véritable, un phénomène que je perçois moi-même,  mais je ne suis pas sûr que votre propos soit sur le même plan et si le reste des exemples que vous avez relevés n'est pas différent des exemples que vous citez je crois que votre question est sans fondement. Si cependant votre propos rejoins celui qui est le mien, alors oui, je reconnais qu'il y a un point en celui-ci. Seulement vous devrez reconnaitre alors que vous posez une question énorme en psycholinguistiques<sup>1</sup>, une question qui ne peut que vous entrainer dans des études de plusieurs années si elles n'ont pas été faites; vous devriez donc essayer de vérifier ce qui existe dans ce domaine de la linguistique, si vous en avez le loisir. Je doute que votre recherche puisse être très fructueuse. J'ajoute que si nous identifions bien tous les deux le même phénomène, il m'apparait comme bien moins important qu'il ne semble l'être pour vous, mais je ne suis pas un linguiste.

<sub>1</sub>  <sub>Je crois même que des notions de sociologie aient une importance dans le processus de recherche.</sub>

Comment: *je crois qu'il n'y a pas de point à votre question.*  Effectivement, je viens de le rajouter.

Comment: @jlliagre Je vois, je viens de relire ma réponse.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr que tu as vraiment compris...

Comment: @jlliagre Mais si, j'ai bien compris : deux points (démonstration intellectuelle, ponctuation) ; on implique  l'un dans des formes qui traitent de l'autre et ça embrouille l'esprit de façon amusante.

Comment: En effet, mais le fait est que la phrase *il n'y a pas de point à votre question* est un pur anglicisme. Aucun francophone natif (de France au moins, je ne sais pas au Canada) ne dit ça. En français, ce pourrait être : *Votre question n'est pas fondée / est sans fondement*. *Point* serait utilisable par exemple dans : *il n'y a pas de point à rajouter à votre question*.

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, d'accord, ça m'échappait ; merci de  signaler ça et pour les détails et suggestions.

Comment: @jlliagre Tu parle des points (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(signe)), non ? La réponse n'a pas eu des points (full stops) initialement.

Comment: @dimitris J'ai pris l'anglicisme de LPH au pied de la lettre en faisant semblant de comprendre qu'il évoquait le **point** d'interrogation qui manquait au titre de ta question et que j'ai rajouté hier.

Comment: Ironique, en lisant l'échange de commentaires ci-dessus, de se dire que la question était à propos de la [popularité](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=petit%2Cpoint&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpetit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoint%3B%2Cc0) du mot *petit*. ;-) Bravo en tous cas pour avoir réussi à surpasser cette multiple confusion !